# new date column for pandas df with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Could you please elucidate me on what I am doing wrong here. I want to create a new date column where the new date will be same as column "inc_cr_date" if the "inc_cr_date_day" is not "Sunday" or "Saturday". When is Saturday or Sunday I want the new column to be "inc_cr_date" +1 and +2 days respectively.

df is:

```
inc_cr_date              inc_cr_date_day
2017-10-26 21:59:28.075  Thursday
2017-10-27 08:17:02.718  Friday
2017-10-22 14:44:07.695  Sunday
```

code (updated):

```
df['inc_cr_date_day'] = df['inc_cr_date'].dt.weekday_name

df['inc_cr_date_adjusted'] = np.select([(df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Saturday'),#condition working
                              (df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Sunday'),#condition working
                              ((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Monday')& (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour > 18 ) & df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute > 30),
                              ((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Monday')& (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour < 9 ) & df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute < 30),
                              ((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Tuesday')& (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour > 18 ) & df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute > 30),
                              ((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Tuesday')& (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour < 9 ) & df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute < 30),
                              ((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Wednesday')& (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour > 18 ) & df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute > 30),
                              ((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Wednesday')& (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour < 9 ) & df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute < 30),
                              ((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Thursday')& (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour > 18 ) & df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute > 30),
                              ((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Thursday')& (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour < 9 ) & df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute < 30),
                              ((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Friday')& (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour > 18 ) & df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute > 30),
                              ((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Friday')& (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour < 9 ) & df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute < 30)],


                           [(df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('2 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('1 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('1 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('0 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('1 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),                            
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('0 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('1 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('0 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('1 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('0 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('3 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('0 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes')],

                           df['inc_cr_date'])
```

Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: instead of  return `['inc_cr_date'] + pd.DateOffset(1)` Try `row['inc_cr_date'] + pd.DateOffset(1)` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing the questions posted is adding timedelta to a `list`  `['inc_cr_date'] + pd.DateOffset(1)`. Try it with `row['inc_cr_date'] + pd.DateOffset(1)`

So instead of if, elseif, else we can use the power of [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), and `+ pd.Timedelta` i.e

```
df['inc_cr_date2'] = np.select([(df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Saturday'),
                                (df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Sunday')],

                               [df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('1 days'),
                                df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('2 days')],

                                df['inc_cr_date'])
```

```
             inc_cr_date inc_cr_date_day            inc_cr_date2
0 2017-10-26 21:59:28.075        Thursday 2017-10-26 21:59:28.075
1 2017-10-27 08:17:02.718          Friday 2017-10-27 08:17:02.718
2 2017-10-22 14:44:07.695          Sunday 2017-10-24 14:44:07.695
```

For specific time we can use normalize and add timedelta of hours you want ie.

```
df['inc_cr_date2'] = np.select([(df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Saturday'),
                              (df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Sunday')],

                           [(df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('1 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours'),
                            (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('2 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours')],

                           df['inc_cr_date'])
```

```
           inc_cr_date inc_cr_date_day            inc_cr_date2
0 2017-10-26 21:59:28.075        Thursday 2017-10-26 21:59:28.075
1 2017-10-27 08:17:02.718          Friday 2017-10-27 08:17:02.718
2 2017-10-22 14:44:07.695          Sunday 2017-10-24 09:00:00.000
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks. I am not familiar with np.select. Need to study it. One last question, could you give me a snip on how could i extend the condition from np.select([(df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Saturday') and also inc_cr_date an hour between 09:00:00 and 20:00:00? thanks.

Comment: You can use multiple condtions like `((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Saturday') & (df['inc_cr_date_day'].dt.hour > 9) & (df['inc_cr_date_day'].dt.hour < 20))`

Comment: one last question (sorry). How could use (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour > 9 with hours and minutes (i.e. 9:30). It appears that dt.hour doesnt recognize the minutes.

Comment: You can do `& df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute < 30`

Comment: I mounted all my conditions but somehow only the first 2 conditions are working (for Staurday and Sunday. All the others do not work as expected as they never move the day to next day and the time is always 9.30, so it means the else condition is never assumed. I updated the code on the question. Any idea what could be?

Comment: Oh my so many conditions were you planning to use if else for this? If you have time like 9:30 then use >= or <= based on situation. I never came across that many conditions before. Better to post a new question in numpy asking why it is not working .

Comment: Sorry, no if else. I mean that the last row of the code is never being assumed , that is not changing anything and new date is equal the old date. Will create new question. Thanks